# Accessing database for mobile web applications

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I have a question about login and accessing database for mobile web applications.

1. Namely, the fact that all the pages are usually in one page separated by ids, how do you send form data using PHP? There are no separate files to send data to.
2. Doesn't opening a connection at the top of the HTML file without logging in cause a security problem? If they do not login successfully, you are essentially redirecting to the same HTML file.

If someone could redirect to a tutorial (which I can't seem to find online) or give an overview, that would be awesome.

```
<?php 
//1. Open connection
//2. Select database
?>

<html>
<body>
<section id="page1">
<form action="page2" method="POST"><!-- since the data needs to be send to #page2, do I just POST to the same html file? -->
</form>
</section>

<section id="page2">
<?php 
//3.query database
//4. display results 
?>
</section>

<section id="page3">
</section>

</body>
</html>
<?php //5. close connection?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can keep separate files in PHP, they don't have to be in the same page. For example, you have a file named login.php.

```
<?php ?>
<html>
    <form action="index.php" method="post>
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <input type="password" name="pasword"/>
   </form>
 </html>
```

Then in your index.php file you would have something like this.

```
<?php
if($_POST['username']=="admin" && $_POST['password']=="admin")
//query database
//display results 
?>
```

So you don't have just one file containing different pages.

2) You can include a main.php file in all your pages and check if user is logged in, if not, redirect him to some other page. In adition you could learn a little bit about session variables.

```
<?php
include("main.php");
?>
```

In your main.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['islogged'])
header("location: otherpage.php";)
?>
```

So if the user is logged in there will be no redirection but other way it will.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1)

Check out  the following link. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp
It explains how to access form data that has been sent to your php page. You need a decent understanding of HTML before you ever start working with PHP.

2)

The user isn't the one logging in. They never see the php code. It stays on the server. What they see is HTML. The connection is so the php page can connect to the database and retrieve information.